# How to maintain EMA predictions after each epoch in tensorflow?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have to see the performance of neural networks based upon exponential moving averages after each epoch. Currently i do this:

```
with tf.Session as sess:
    train(sess):
        while i in epochs():
            model_build(reuse = True, getter=None)
            run_epoch(updates_ema_as_well)
            model_build(reuse = True, getter = custom_getter_that_returns_EMA_for_each_variable)
            model.predict(validation_data)
```

The problem with this is, i think it will build multiple graphs each time i am calling `model_build()`. I am not well versed at tensorflow to handle this properly. Please suggest me improvements in my approach

Comment: The way to handle this is to use two models (i.e. two sets of TensorFlow variables) 

`model_1`: for updating normally with SGD, 

`model_2`: the other one updated like `(1- alpha) model_2 + alpha model_1`

You can then use TensorFlow `tf.Optimizer.minimize` operation to update the `model_1` and then use `tf.assign` to assign the EMA value to `model_2`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: this i have already implemented. But the point is i have to implement mean teachers using this so i would be needing EMA predictions on unlabeled parts of the batches after each epoch and i am doing it the way i have described in the question but that is building multiple graphs

Comment: To me the problem you're trying to solve is not clear from the description. Can you add more details? For example what does `model_build` do? What is `updates_ema_as_well`?